# SQLce create table "index field" explanation (SQL Management Studio)?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm new to databases, and now creating SQLCE database in Management Studio. There is a value in brackets; **[UQ_*Users*_0000000000000028]**, which seems a bit random to me, so would just like to ask if someone could explain this field?

Is it just simply required to be a unique field? 
 Is there any reason why I would want to change it to something else than what SSMS scripts?

cheers!

```
CREATE TABLE [Users] (
  [UserID] int NOT NULL
.....
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX [UQ__Users__0000000000000028] ON [Users] ([UserID] ASC);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I'd recommend changing it's name to make some kind of sense (useful when querying the system views), for example UQ_Users_UserID.

This was probably originally created with something like :-

CREATE TABLE [Users] (
   [UserID] int UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED,
.....

so SQL Server will have assigned it it's own (non-helpful) constraint name.

Answer (score 0):

They are [default constraint names](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/default-constraint-names) designed to provide uniqueness across servers. I always name mine to avoid scripting issues.